# What is negative zero and what is its use?

Tags: language-agnostic, numbers

I happened to come across a question here that mentioned trying to assign a float to `-0.0` or something along those lines. However, from what I have read so far negative zero is the same as positive zero, so why not just have zero? Why do the two exist?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: Google "negative zero", and you'll find lots of info, including plenty on this site.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thank you for the link. It was very nice and clear to read. Don't know how I didn't come across that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each possible floating point valuue actually represents a small range of possible real world numbers (because there are only a finite number of possible floating point numbers but an infinite number of actual values). So 0.0 represents a value anywhere between 0.0 and a very small positive number, whereas -0.0 represents a value anywhere between 0.0 and a very small negative value.

Note however they when we compare 0.0 and -0.0 they are considered to be equal, even though the actual representation in bits is different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now, but what is the use of this? Also, just out of interest, how are the two represented in bits?

Comment: The "use" is mathematical - for some algorithms you need to preserve the sign of a value even when it becomes vanishingly small. 0.0 is 0x00000000, -0.0 is 0x80000000 - the only difference is the sign bit (bit 23).